# How to determinate if the current Windows user have write permisions over an specific file using power shell

Tags: windows, powershell, automation

I'm trying to write a power shell program/routine which add two new lines at the end of a txt file, and also do many others stuffs.

I want to prevent unsuccessfull tries of file writing, due to lack of write permisions over the file. So I want to test if the current user has write permisions over a specific file.

I try

```
$Files = "C:\Program Files\MySoftware\SWVersion\OtherSubFolder\DesiredFile.txt"
Get-Acl -Path $Files | Format-List AccessToString
```

but this display the permisions for all users over the file, but I only want to know if the current user can or can't write the desired file.

Any help or guidance would be apreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to filter the results of the **AccessToString** property for the current user, then given that each line begins with the user in **DOMAIN\username** format, all you need to do is:

```
(Get-Acl $File).AccessToString | findstr "$env:USERDOMAIN\$env:USERNAME"
```

If you want to get the **FileSystemAccessRule** object so you can do something with it, do it this way:

```
(Get-Acl $File).Access | ?{$_.IdentityReference -eq "$env:USERDOMAIN\$env:USERNAME"}
```

That's probably more useful if you want the check whether the user has certain permissions:

```
if (((Get-Acl $File).Access | ?{$_.IdentityReference -eq "$env:USERDOMAIN\$env:USERNAME"}).FileSystemRights -match 'Modify') {
  # Do whatever it is you want to do if the user has Modify permissions
}
```

(Sure, you could apply `-match 'Modify'` to the results of the first command, and that usually wouldn't be a problem, but it would break if the domain or username contained "modify". Unlikely, but it's better practice to just match against the property you're interested in.)

Note: I changed **$Files** to **$File** because you're only assigning a path to a single file. If **$Files** is intended to be an array of paths to multiple files, pipe it to a **Foreach-Object** block like this:

```
$Files | %{(Get-Acl $_).Access | ?{$_.IdentityReference -eq "$env:USERDOMAIN\$env:USERNAME"}
```

Comment: Your solution is great. Thanks for your help. Do you know  where I can find all possible access types that (Get-Acl $File).AccessToString can return? I have seen FullControl, ReadAndExecute, Synchronize, but I want to know all possible values that this execution can return in order to analice which of these roles/permisions can modify the specified file.

Comment: `[Enum]::GetNames([System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights])` will give you a full list of possible **FileSystemRights** values.

Comment: BTW, please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Rather than thanking people in comments, you should mark the answer that best resolved the question as accepted, and upvote any answers you found useful (which may include the accepted answer). I see that you've posted 9 questions with 0 marked as accepted, so I wanted to make sure you're familiar with the system.

Comment: In some cases your suggested solution does not gives me the right answer. This method give me an "wrong" answer when the user has rights over the requested file, but in a implicit way. For example, when the current user is asociated to an specific user group, and that group have Write Access, full control, etc,  over the file, but for the user access was not specified directly (in a individually way) over the file (or folder) . Do you know how to deal with that?

Answer (score 1):

You can take a more direct approach:

```
$Files = "C:\Program Files\MySoftware\SWVersion\OtherSubFolder\DesiredFile.txt"

try { 
     $filetest =  [IO.FILE]::OpenWrite($Files)
     $filetest.close()
   }
catch { "Unable to open file for write: $($Files.fullname) `n`n $($Error[0])"}
```

Comment: Your solution is interesing. But, how can I close the file after a successfully execution?

Comment: Updated the script.  The OpenWrite will return a FileStream object.  Invoke the close() method on that to close the file.